# Error while starting appium

Tags: windows, npm, appium

While running the appium server on windows 8 i am getting the error message as:

> module.js:340 >     throw err; >           ^ > Error: Cannot find
>   module 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\main.js' >     at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) >     at
>   Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) >     at
>   Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) >     at startup
>   (node.js:119:16) >     at node.js:902:3 >

Comment: In your C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\ folder do you have a main.js file?

Comment: i was unable to find main.js.

Comment: I have installed the appium from https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/ website and AppiumForWindows_1_4_0_0.zip this file.

Comment: The problem is that module.js expects a main.js to exist (you are running the main module) and it is not found in the expected location

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to improper installation.
Use the below link to download and install latest appium

https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/AppiumForWindows_1_4_16_1.zip

Let me know if issue persists

Answer (score 1):

You Should build the Project to get your main.js...

Go to Appium folder and invoke ./reset.sh to build your node project

Recommended:

Clone the appium project from GITHUB and build your node project like i mentioned above. So, you can update easily to the very latest update of appium